# Toast/snackbar is not finishing announcement, focus changes to another view before announcement finishes

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I noticed that talkback is not finishing its announcement of the to snackbar before focusing back onto another element. Is there a way for me to force the snackbar to finish its announcement before focusing onto another element.

Requesting focus onto the snackbar itself has not worked, along with that doing the same thing with a postDelayed (500 ms delay) is also not working. I am really stumped on what to do any help would be appreciated.

edit: initially said toast instead of snackbar corrected that

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the text of the Toast is too
long. Try and keep it as short you can.

Other thing you can try is using `Snackbar` as it offers more control over display duration and can ensure that accessibility announcements are completed before any focus changes occur.

Also checkout [AccessibilityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager) and [announceForAccessibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#announceForAccessibility(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Hi I am using snackbar, would increasing the duration potentially fix this issue currently its at the default for a long toast? Have also tried using announceForAccessibility() that did not work but I have not tried increasing the duration

Comment: No I haven't used  announceForAccessibility(), using Snackbar with increased duration worked for me.